# Progress Bar and Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar

I have this Progress Bar class (Testing threading)

```
public class ProgressBarUpdate
    {
        //Add getters and setters
        static MainGUI theForm = (MainGUI)Application.OpenForms[0];
        ProgressBar pBarCur = theForm.pBarCur; //Yes, accessing public for now
        bool updateCur = false;
        bool stopCur = false;
        bool showMax = false;
    public ProgressBarUpdate()
    {

    }
    public void resetCur()
    {
        pBarCur.Value = 0;
    }
    public void DoCurUpdate()
    {
        while (!stopCur)
        {
            if (pBarCur.Value < (pBarCur.Maximum / 10) * 9)
                pBarCur.PerformStep();
            if (showMax)
            {
                pBarCur.Value = pBarCur.Maximum;
                showMax = false;
            }
        }

    }
public void StopCur()
        {
            stopCur = true;
        }
        public void UpdateCur()
        {
            updateCur = true;
        }
        public void UpdateToMax()
        {
            showMax = true;
        }
```

And then I'm calling all of it in a different class A to update the GUI from there:

```
ProgressBarUpdate updateBar = new ProgressBarUpdate();

        Thread currentProgressUpdater = new Thread(new ThreadStart(updateBar.DoCurUpdate));

        try
        {
            currentProgressUpdater.Start();

            currentProgressUpdater.Join();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
```

And after I run it, I get the dialog where my application has stopped responding (right away) and then it asks me to close. Am I not implementing Threads correctly? Or am I missing a step?

Comment: If you don't want to use the BackgroundWorker(), make your ProgressBarUpdate() class raise custom `events` to pass progress out.  The main form would subscribe to those events when it creates an instance of ProgressBarUpdate(), and then update its controls based on the received information when those events come in.  Be sure to properly use delegates and Invoke() to update the GUI to avoid cross-thread exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the call to `currentProgressUpdater.Join();`.  You're blocking the UI thread.

The whole point of creating a new thread is to allow the UI thread to continue on processing UI events.  You aren't letting it do that.  Starting a thread and then immediately joining on it isn't really any different than just executing the code in line.

You're also accessing controls from the method running in the new thread.  That won't work.  UI controls can only be accessed from the UI thread.

Comment: Is there a way to do the "smart" progress bar update? Like calling the update method from inside another method that has a for loop and update after every iteration?

Comment: @Alexey It's not clear what you want.  You can use a `BackgroundWorker` to represent a long running operation, and it has built in support for progress updating that you can use to have an event fired when you want to up date the UI with the current progress.  See the MSDN page for BackgroundWorker for examples.

Comment: Or would you suggest put the progress bar in a pop-up form, which is a new thread, and then pass in values from the main form to this new form to update the progress bar. That way the progress bar components aren't locked.

Comment: @Alexey I **highly** discourage you from using multiple UI threads.  It'll be a nightmare; don't do it.  It's quite a bit harder to manage correctly, not easier.

Comment: I want to make two progress bar, one for intermediate process and one for the total process. Intermediate is 1 for loop, total is the whole executing operation. I want to show the user a progress bar for each one and provide a cancel button, so after every intermediate operation, it checks if cancel was hit, and stops executing. I'm stuck on making the progress bar run alongside the main process. (Tried doing it in one thread ALL of it, and got laughed at by Jon Skeet, so I assumed I was doing it wrong).

Comment: @Alexey Jon Skeet said that he couldn't understand what you were actually doing as you didn't provide enough information.  He didn't laugh at you, he was asking you for more information.  You choose not to provide it, so he couldn't help you.  The general process you just described is simple enough; there really isn't any problem doing that.  You without seeing your specific implementation it's hard to say what's wrong with it or why it isn't working.  In general it won't be much different than a single progress bar.  Try getting that working first and then add the second onto it.

Comment: So you would suggest sticking to BackgroundWorker?

Comment: @Alexey I see no convincing reason not to do so.  You could alternatively use the `Progress` class which may be a bit easier with multiple concepts of "progress", but you certainly don't *need* to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are in an infinite loop here `while (!stopCur)`

You never set `stopCur` to `true`.

Comment: That code isn't in the UI thread, so that wouldn't cause the UI to block.

Comment: @Servy the UI thread is waiting for it, so as you say in your answer, that doesn't really make a difference here